# How to start a terminal program in vterm from org mode?

Tags: org-mode, shell

I'm currently using xterm using following line below to open `data.csv` with `visidata` from **xterm**. How can I achieve similar behaviour though with **vterm** instead?

example.org:

`[[elisp:(start-process "" nil "/usr/bin/xterm" "-e" "visidata" "./data.csv"]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the following should work

```
[[elisp:(with-current-buffer (vterm) (vterm-send-string "visidata ./data.csv\n"))]]
```